# Jersey 2: What replaces FEATURE_FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404?

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

What is the Jersey 2 equivalent of [ServletContainer.FEATURE_FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.9/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.html#FEATURE_FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404) from Jersey 1?

[ServletContainer.FEATURE_FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.9/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.html#FEATURE_FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404) is defined as:

> If true and a 404 response with no entity body is returned from either the runtime or the application then the runtime forwards the request to the next filter in the filter chain

**Please explain why you are downvoting. I can't improve the question/answer if you don't provide an explanation of what is wrong.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties you should be using are [ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletProperties.html#FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404) and [ServletProperties.FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletProperties.html#FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX).

[ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletProperties.html#FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404) is defined as:

> If set to true and a 404 response with no entity body is returned from either the runtime or the application then the runtime forwards the request to the next filter in the filter chain.

[ServletProperties.FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletProperties.html#FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX) is defined as:

> If set the regular expression is used to match an incoming servlet path URI to some web page content such as static resources or JSPs to be handled by the underlying servlet engine.

Answer (score 1):

@gili is correct. For a complete running example of the jersey 2.x config check out my simple toy project on github:

https://github.com/depsypher/flapjack

Essentially you'll have to run the Jersey ServletContainer as a filter and provide the `jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404` property as an init param.

Here's an example of the setup using Spring Boot; the web.xml equivalent should be pretty obvious:

```
FilterRegistrationBean filter = new FilterRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer());
filter.addInitParameter("jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404", "true");
```